# Can git / github / gitlab detect the operating system the commit was sent from?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

If I have a repo in gitlab. Is it possible to detect the operating system a commit was sent from?

Or is this impossible?

Unusual request I know! I've googled a lot but finding it difficult to find the right search query. Maybe there is a Git spec that would help.

**Edit:
This is an employer requirement to use a given linux computer that is awful and terribly slow. I'm hoping I can use my personal windows machine without being traced.**

Comment: Try not mix up git with gitlab/github. --- Afaik git does not store the os in the commit metadata.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git doesn't store the OS or version information in the commit, so in the general case, there's no way to know.

However, you may be able to use some heuristics to guess the OS.  For example, if the repository uses a `working-tree-encoding=UTF-16LE-BOM` in `.gitattributes`, it's likely that the file in question was committed on Windows.  Similarly, if there's a non-UTF-8 commit encoding (which tends to be extremely rare these days), then that may also provide some indication, since some encodings are more common on some platforms than others.  You may also be able to guess based on the author or committer information, knowing, for example, that I always commit from a Linux (or, rarely, macOS) machine.

However, for most projects, there isn't any way to know other than by guessing based on other metadata, and other than the author or committer information, most repositories don't have such relevant metadata.

Similarly, GitHub and GitLab have no way of knowing this, either, since it isn't possible to know for certain what OS a remote system is using, although in some cases they may log or provide the user-agent and/or SSH banner information used to push the commit, which can differ based on system.  However, that doesn't tell you what system the commit was created on, only what system pushed it, and they don't have to be the same.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! "You may also be able to guess based on the author or committer information". Where is this information? How would I access it?

Comment: "However, that doesn't tell you what system the commit was created on, only what system pushed it, and they don't have to be the same."
Oh so you could detect the OS that the commit was pushed from? How would that work?
Thanks again!! :D

Comment: @HombreLobo Well, what happens during a `git push`?

Comment: The author and committer information can be fetched from `git log`.  See the documentation for `--pretty`.  Git for Windows includes a distinguishing version number, and some distro versions of OpenSSH include the distro name.  However, I don't believe GitHub exposes that information publicly, so there's no way for _you_ to find that information out.

Answer (score 1):

No and why would you even care?

I may be writing code on my linux box that is for a Windows application but pushed that code to the repository from my old Dos laptop.